# Is it necessary to destroy the class instances in my loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Suppose I have a loop which creates a new instance of a EF Class to add to databasde table in each loop iteration:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    InvestmentTransactionStaging newRecord = new()
    {
        UserId = UserId,
        InvestmentTransactionTypeId = interestRepaymentTransactionTypeId,
        InvestmentEntityId = InvestmentEntityId,
        Description = record.LoanReference,
        Date = DateTime.Parse(record.Date),
    };
    _context.InvestmentTransactionsStaging.Add(newRecord);
}
```

Now normally, in the languages I am used to such as php it is not important destroy the instance after the call to _context..Add(), the garbage Collector takes care of it.  If I omit this as I have above, would this then potentially cause any issues with memory in C#?  Do I need to destroy the instance on each itertation that it is instamtiated and if so how?  (I could not use the Disapose method as it complains the method is unavailable.

Comment: You cannot "destroy" objects in C#. Problem solved.

Comment: If the object you are creating is truly a `class` and not a `struct`, then it is not being destroyed or garbage collected, unless that "staging" object fails to hold on to it.  But If the object you are creating implements `IDispose`, then you need to put a `using` statement in front of it.

Comment: Technically you don't have to create the instance as a variable, you can just do it all in one line: `_context.InvestmentTransactionsStaging.Add(new() { UserId = UserId, ... });`

Comment: No. You are creating an object and assigning a reference to it to `newRecord` and  adding a further reference to it to some form of List, I assume for some future use.  Do you want to destroy the object or the reference to that object?  `newRecord` is just a reference and goes out of scope once the loop completes.  It will be dealt with by the Garbage Collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created objects are automatically destructed when no longer reachable

Meaning, any object created, lives only as long as the running code is still between curly braces, where it was instantiated

---

**Update - Going deep**

As mentioned by computercarguy (as well as in the comments), *it's not accurate to say the object only lives inside the code block in which it was declared*, cause the object lives as long as there is a reference to it in the program.

Meaning, if you declare an instance called `newRecord`, and you don't assign **it** to any other pointer which has been declared outside of that code block in which `newRecord` was declared, then yes, when compiler exits that code block (*and goes through the steps of **Garbage Collection***), it is removed from the memory, but if there is another pointer, for example `oldRecord`, and you assign the value (address) of the `newRecord` to it before the end of the code block, then the object isn't removed from memory, for it is still being pointed to, by a pointer ie `oldRecord`.

In conclusion: *[The garbage collector checks for objects that are no longer being used by the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers)*, so there is no point in removing the object manually, because the GC does it for you, if it is safe to remove the object, for it can cause problems when implemented by us imperfect humans ☺

Comment: That's a vast oversimplification.

Comment: Well, I see it to be that simple. If I'm wrong, I would like nothing more than you teaching me

Comment: To be fair, it is "effectively" that simple. The reality is that garbage collection goes through several phases before the unreferenced objects are truly reaped. It's worth a read of various resources about .NET GC out there. Far more than I can do justice in comments. In your answer, *only* should really be *about*. Pragmatically, application programmers should generally "not worry about it".

Comment: I see, thank you @Kit, I'll read more on that. ♥

Comment: [Polite] I would suggest that this answer is a little misleading.  The reference to the object (which is what `newRecord` is) lives only as long as the code block in which it is declared.  The object itself is only destroyed by the GC when the application has released all references to it.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, thank you, the collected wisdom of the group was added to the answer ☺ ♥

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Even if you set `newRecord` to null, you wouldn't have destroyed the class instance. It's still accessible in the `_context.InvestmentTransactionsStaging` object. (In this case, `_context` is probably a database.)

Long answer:

I might be getting into the weeds here, but your variable is just a pointer to a memory address where the class instance/object was created. When you null out that variable, you simply simply remove the value of the memory address from the variable, not the object. The object remains if other variables are pointing to the same memory address. Automatic garbage collection happens when that object's memory address is no longer being pointed to by any variables or other objects. This is when things get "destroyed".

This happens in many modern languages, not just C#. It might happen differently in C# than it does in PHP, but it ends up with similar results.

Even saying that the object is destroyed is not 100% correct, since the values aren't usually removed. The memory address is just used for something else and overwritten as needed. That can be within the same program or it could be returned to the OS for it to allocate to another process.

And this doesn't cover the complete lifecycle of objects, but it's the most useful explanation until you need to get into much lower level programming of microcontrollers and other embedded systems.

Comment: Yes, nice, if your declaration is no longer reachable, but the memory is still being pointed, then the destructor doesn't invoke. Thank you, hadn't though of it that way

Comment: @IMm0rtal, correct. If no variable points to a memory address, but the property of another object points to it, the object remains. Like Kit mentioned in their comment on your answer, the GC sometimes needs multiple passes to free up all memory when objects reference other objects.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I need to read more on the subject. ♥

Comment: @IMm0rtal, I learned this over 20 years ago in college. I can't say I've needed to actually know this much detail in my 10 years of professional software development, and I didn't need it in the 6-8 years before I learned it, either. Like Kit mentioned, your answer is all that most programmers really need to know. If you know more than that, you basically understand why manual GC isn't necessary and will get into "conversations" with other devs when they try to do it.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right ☺, I'm just super into "not necessarily usable details", I just like to go deep. But you're right, a lot of the times, you will never know a lot of the stuff you learned